# Unexplainable segmentation fault on iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, segmentation-fault

I'm having this very disturbing problem when running our app in the device. Everything goes fine with the Debug scheme but with the Distribution profile (the one with the AdHoc certificate for code signing) the app crashes and the only error I get in the device's login this one:

```
Tue Oct  4 10:49:44 unknown com.apple.debugserver-48[670] <Warning>: 21 [029e/0803]: RNBRunLoopLaunchInferior DNBProcessLaunch() returned error: 'DRHT'
Tue Oct  4 10:49:44 unknown com.apple.debugserver-48[670] <Warning>: error: failed to launch process (null): failed to get the task for process 672
Tue Oct  4 10:49:44 unknown com.apple.debugserver-48[670] <Warning>: 22 [029e/1403]: error: ::read ( 4, 0x2fee59f0, 1024 ) => -1 err = Bad file descriptor (0x00000009)
Tue Oct  4 10:49:44 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.oos.kraken[0x3f17]) Bug: launchd_core_logic.c:3252 (24226):3
Tue Oct  4 10:49:44 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.oos.kraken[0x3f17]) Bug: launchd_core_logic.c:2681 (24226):10
Tue Oct  4 10:49:44 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.oos.kraken[0x3f17]) Working around 5020256. Assuming the job crashed.
Tue Oct  4 10:49:44 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Warning>: (UIKitApplication:com.oos.kraken[0x3f17]) Job appears to have crashed: Segmentation fault
Tue Oct  4 10:49:44 unknown SpringBoard[24] <Warning>: Application '11870.com' exited abnormally with signal 11: Segmentation fault
```

I'm really lost and have no idea of what can be happening. What does it mean by " APPEARS to have crashed" doesn't it know when there is a problem with an app?

Anybody came across this problem before? I am using xcode 4 and the device is an iphone 3G although it also happens in an iphone 4.

PD: I've tried Zombies with no luck.

Comment: I have a similar problem. No solution yet. Mine shows the splash screen on launch, then crashes on the device. If I launch manually on the device the app works fine. Is this similar to what yours does? I'm sure the issue is something is wrong in the build targets/schemes. But XCode doesn't just let you "reset" these targets to their original state as they were when you first created the project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the end, the solution was to restart the iPhone, since some data got corrupted. After the reboot everything was working normally.

Should have thought of the classic "Have you tried turning it off and on again?"

Comment: Switching phone off and on may temporarily solve problem, But we have to find the real problem that caused it. In my case it happened in random. The real culprit was __bridge i used to typecast struct to id. It occured only when memory was low.

Comment: Well if restart fixes the problem and it happens at random it may be a platform problem and not an code issue. All we can do (since the system is closed) is to troubleshoot users and hope Apple bothers to fix that some day.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's an apple issue. Instruments should be used to find the actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar segmentation fault when installing an ad-hoc build onto an iPad 1 running 5.1.1.  Turns out you can't install an ad-hoc build on anything before iOS6 that includes Arm64.  I removed Arm64 from "Valid Architectures", rebuilt, and the ad-hoc build then installs fine on the iPad 1.

Comment: Do you know if the application including Arm64 build will install properly on iPad1 5.1.1 from AppStore (release, not ad-hoc version)?

Comment: I believe that it will, but I'm not totally sure.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar seemingly random crashes, esp. on an 3G test device. The app worked just fine in debug mode, however the crashes started to appear in adhoc builds.

The "solution" in my case was to disable most, if not all, compiler optimizations for the release/adhoc builds.